# Allow only 1 selection in a price set with multiple price fields

Tags: civimember

We offer individual and joint membership with a couple of different rates for each type. I have created a price set that has 2 price fields and each price field has a couple of options. I want to set the price set so that only one option can be ticked across both price fields. There isn't an option for this and but I hope someone has a solution. I can put all types of membership into 1 price field but it reduces the system options and makes laying out the contribution page harder. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the price fields are independent, and the design limits you to putting all the membership types/flavours into one price field if you need to force only one.

Of course, you could write some javascript to do something like what you want, though that would be a bit of a hack.

A simple alternative is to create separate contribution/membership pages for each membership type - so the visitor would be presented with different links for each membership type before getting a form. That allows your form to be simpler and have additional membership-type-specific messaging and behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think your simple alternative is probably the best approach as it would also allow a different payment provider for one of the options if we needed it.